# What tool can check internet TX/RX status as top/htop?

Tags: ethernet, utilities

For processor usage, we can use top or htop.

For internet status, I would like to know the current TX/RX status, any command/tool to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nload`.  From its manpage:

> nload is a console application which monitors network traffic and bandwidth usage in real time. It visualizes the in- and outgoing traffic using two graphs and provides additional info like the total amount of transfered data and min/max network usage.

Another tool that you could find useful is [`iptraf`](http://iptraf.seul.org/).  From Wikipedia:

> [...] IPTraf has the following characteristics:
>
> - IP traffic monitor displays information about network traffic.
> - General statistics Interfaces.
> - LAN statistics module that discovers host and displays data about their activity.
> - Monitor TCP, UDP account showing the network packets for port connections of applications.
> - Use the "raw socket interface" that takes kernel allowing it to be used by a wide range of "network cards". [sic]

Comment: FYI on Ubuntu 20.04 I didn't get a graph (only stats) from nload and iptraf has been deprecated to make way for iptraf-ng, that doesn't show a graph but does provide a useful wireshark type of continuous monitoring.